# What algorithm is more efficient to shift every elements in a java array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

this is the first algorithm that i made:

```
int tmp = null;
for (int i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--){
    tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    arr[i-1] = tmp;
}
```

and this is the second algorithm which my computer teacher says to me:

```
int tmp = null;
for (int i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

help me about which is more efficient. In my experiment using

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

this method with an array with 100000 datas,
the first algorithm was faster but my teacher says the second one would be faster in bigger databases with various things. I know that a LinkedList would do good, but i want to know about this problem.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to do - but the second one is clearly O(n^2), whereas the first is O(n), i.e. the second one gets slower quicker for bigger inputs.

Comment: I won't answer your question directly, but I believe it's better to remember number of shifts and write your own get method which would handle number of shifts.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised that your teacher is claiming that the second algorithm is faster.

Comment: But the first one can be made faster again, by avoiding two of the assignments: `int tmp = arr[arr.length - 1]; for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) { arr[i] = arr[i - 1]; } arr[0] = tmp;` or something like that.

Comment: Also: `int tmp = null;` isn't legal.

Comment: I don't know what the second one should be doing, but it's definitely not the same as the first one. Using a direct copy and paste and using array from 1 to 10, I got for the first one `10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` as expected, and for the second one `6 1 2 9 10 3 4 7 8 5`

Comment: I get that this is for the academic purpose of studying algorithms. But the most efficient way to perform operations like these is probably `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithms [do different things](http://ideone.com/LktHQm):

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
First: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Second: [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

so any discussion of their relative efficiency is irrelevant, as they are not functionally the same.

---

However, simply in terms of the time taken to do *something*, the first algorithm is `O(n)`, whereas the second is `O(n^2)`. As such, the time taken to execute the first will grow more slowly than the second as the input size grows, so your teacher is wrong.

---

Note that the first is doing a lot of unnecessary work: it is repeatedly swapping the last element of the array all the way down to the start of the array. As such, it can be done more quickly like this:

```
int tmp = arr[arr.length - 1];
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
  arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
}
arr[0] = tmp;
```